# is it safe to interrupt writing objects while pushing to heroku git repo?

Tags: git, heroku

As its getting too slow to complete the push, I am still not sure if I canceled the push operation would be a wise thing to do or not? I am thinking to push later ..

Any one can advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git push is [atomic on a per-ref level](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Atomicity-of-git-push-operation-td4208296.html), which means you won't know what commit was accepted and what was not.
(and that is even more problematic when [multiple branches are pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15798641/6309))

A subsequent push would only push the remaining commits, so if you don't mind having an heroku with an unknown number of commits, you can interrupt and resume later.